# Can you say: "I wanted to ask, so I could know.."

Tags: questions, past-tense

On an email I saw this sentence and was wondering what it means?

> I wanted to ask you a few questions, so I would know what to start with.

Does it mean that after I ask, I will know what to start with?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words which are missing, but understood nevertheless, could be, for example (in brackets and in the past tense, looking back in time),

> I wanted to ask you a few questions, so [that when I got some answers] I would know what to start with.

Or, in the present-and-future tenses:

> I want to ask you a few questions, so [that when I get some answers] I will know what to start with.

Even without those extra words, however, your sentence makes perfectly good sense.